# How can I set the size of the child form base from the free space of the mdi container form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

My problem is that I want the child form to occupy the free space of the MDI container

Here's the code I tried

In my MDI container form load event I have this line of code calling the child form

```
childform = new ppt.MyChildForm();
            childform.MdiParent = this;
            childform.Size = childform.MdiParent.ClientSize;
            childform.Show();
```

But what happen is that I think the child form is larger than its parent because it contains a scrollbar how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: AutoScrollMargin is 0, Containers Dock property?

Comment: yes, there is not dock property in child form?

Comment: I think that `AutoSize` overrides the `Size` property. As for `Dock`, set the Dock property of the child form to `Dock.Fill` and it will occupy the entire client size of its parent.

Comment: childform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill?

Comment: Yes. (Have to write 15 chars...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `AutoSize` property is set to true, changing of `Size` has no effect.
A better practice is to set the `Dock` property of the child form to `DockStyle.Fill`. It will always fill the entire client size of its parent, so you have not to worry about parent resizing.